# Ubuntu 17.10 Nginx Setup Error

Tags: nginx, proxy, ubuntu-17.04

I am trying to download packages (for proxychains specifically) and I keep getting dialogue that tells me that dpkg was interrupted, but every time I enter 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' it results in the error shown below:

```
lily-hammer@lilyhammer-H97N:~$ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor         preset: en
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-12-01 11:16:31 CST; 6h ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
 Main PID: 1198 (nginx)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─1198 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_pro
           ├─1199 nginx: worker process
           ├─1200 nginx: worker process
           ├─1201 nginx: worker process
           └─1202 nginx: worker process

Dec 01 11:16:31 lilyhammer-H97N systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web     serv
Dec 01 11:16:31 lilyhammer-H97N systemd[1]: Started A high performance web     serve

lily-hammer@lilyhammer-H97N:~$ systemctl nginx restart
Unknown operation nginx.
lily-hammer@lilyhammer-H97N:~$ systemctl nginx.service restart
Unknown operation nginx.service.
lily-hammer@lilyhammer-H97N:~$ sudo apt-get install proxychains
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'     to correct the problem. 
lily-hammer@lilyhammer-H97N:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up nginx-full (1.13.6-2) ...
^Cdpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libproxychains3:amd64 (3.1-7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
nginx depends on nginx-full (<< 1.13.6-2.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.13.6-2.1~)     |     nginx-extras (<< 1.13.6-2.1~); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-full (>= 1.13.6-2) | nginx-light (>= 1.13.6-2) | nginx-extras (>= 1.13.6-2); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of set:
 set depends on nginx; however:
  Package nginx is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full which provides nginx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package set (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up proxychains (3.1-7) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
 nginx
```

Comment: If you put four spaces before each line it formats it as code and makes it readable.

Comment: Just fixed it! @Tim

Comment: I think if you read the error messages carefully you'll find they're telling you what the problem is. "Package nginx is not configured yet" stands out as a clue